# Select rows with max of duplicates along with distinct data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a scenario in which I need to get the last 3 hours data from a table, by joining it with another table. Please find the 2 tables below

**1.PURCHASE TABLE**

```
| PURCHASE_ID | ORDER_NO | PRODUCT_TYPE | PURCHASE_DATE       | CREATE_DATE         | MODIFIED_DATE       |
|-------------|----------|--------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|    500      | 612356   |  FOOD        | 2020-02-26 08:26:34 | 2020-02-26 08:26:34 | 2020-02-26 08:26:34 |
|    501      | 975432   |  FOOD        | 2020-02-26 08:29:12 | 2020-02-26 08:29:12 | 2020-02-26 08:29:12 |
|    502      | 156712   |  ELECTRONICS | 2020-02-26 08:32:18 | 2020-02-26 08:32:18 | 2020-02-26 08:32:18 |
```

**1.PURCHASE_DETAIL TABLE**

```
| PURCHASE_DETAIL_ID | PURCHASE_ID | MESSAGE_STATUS | CREATE_DATE         | MODIFIED_DATE      |   
|--------------------|-------------|----------------|---------------------|--------------------|
|    1011            |      500    |      FAIL      | 2020-02-26 08:27:14 | 2020-02-26 08:27:14|
|    1012            |      500    |      SUCCESS   | 2020-02-26 08:27:56 | 2020-02-26 08:27:56|
|    1013            |      501    |      FAIL      | 2020-02-26 08:29:14 | 2020-02-26 08:29:14|
|    1014            |      501    |      SUCCESS   | 2020-02-26 08:29:58 | 2020-02-26 08:29:58|
|    1015            |      501    |      SUCCESS   | 2020-02-26 08:30:02 | 2020-02-26 08:30:02|
|    1016            |      501    |      FAIL      | 2020-02-26 08:30:37 | 2020-02-26 08:30:37|
|    1017            |      501    |      SUCCESS   | 2020-02-26 08:31:22 | 2020-02-26 08:31:22|
|    1018            |      502    |      FAIL      | 2020-02-26 08:32:24 | 2020-02-26 08:32:24|
|    1019            |      502    |      SUCCESS   | 2020-02-26 08:32:49 | 2020-02-26 08:32:49|
|    1020            |      502    |      FAIL      | 2020-02-26 08:33:03 | 2020-02-26 08:33:03|
```

The result should be only the one with the latest `MESSAGE_STATUS` as failure and the table is huge, I just need the last 3 hours data only.

As the result I would like to have the following data (I need the `ORDER_NO` only)

**1.PURCHASE TABLE**

```
| PURCHASE_ID | ORDER_NO | PRODUCT_TYPE |
|-------------|----------|--------------|
|    502      | 156712   |  ELECTRONICS |
```

The best query I came up with is

```
SELECT PURCHASE_ID, ORDER_NO, PRODUCT_TYPE FROM PURCHASE WHERE PURCHASE_ID IN (
SELECT A.PURCHASE_ID FROM PURCHASE A INNER JOIN
(SELECT PURCHASE_ID, MAX(PURCHASE_DETAIL_ID) AS NEW_ID, MESSAGE_STATUS 
FROM PURCHASE_DETAIL WHERE CREATE_DATE > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 HOUR) GROUP BY PURCHASE_ID) B
ON A.PURCHASE_ID = B.PURCHASE_ID AND A.PURCHASE_DETAIL_ID = B.NEW_ID 
AND A.MESSAGE_STATUS = "FAIL"
)
```

But this is not giving me the expected results. Can anyone please have a look and let me know what I am missing. I am still a novice at SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by doing inner join and order by clauses

```
SELECT PURCHASE_ID, ORDER_NO, PRODUCT_TYPE
FROM purchase p INNER JOIN purchase_detail pd  ON p.purchase_id = pd.purchase_id WHERE 
message_status='fail' AND pd.create_date BETWEEN date.now() AND date.now()-3 ORDER BY 
pd.create_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will fetch all records within three hours window and fetch the latest record which has the MESSAGE_STATUS as fail

Answer (score 0):

> I have a scenario in which I need to get the last 3 hours data from a table, by joining it with another table. Please find the 2 tables below

This sounds like a `join` with filtering:

```
select p.*, . . .   -- if you want columns from `pd`
from purchase p join
     purchase_detail pd
     on p.purchase_id = pd.purchase_id
where pd.create_date > now() - interval 3 hour and
      pd.message_status = 'FAIL';
```

For performance, I would recommend an index on `purchase_detail(message_status, create_date, purchase_id)`.

Comment: Thank you. Since the records getting updated within a few minutes, there are chances for duplicates. I haven't tried out this query, but I will have `FAIL` coming multiple times, and I want to pick up only the rows with last record as `FAIL` . I think we need more modifications. I believe the above query will return all 3 rows from the PURCHASE table, as there is a `FAIL` entry for each record within the last 3 hour time window.

Comment: @SurajMuraleedharan . . . That is not the question you asked here.  You should ask a *new* question.

Comment: Sorry, In my question, I already mentioned, 
    The result should be only the one with the latest MESSAGE_STATUS as failure     and the table is huge, I just need the last 3 hours data only.